# How do you pass an array through systemd EnvironmentFile?

Tags: systemd, rhel, environment-variables

```
[root@vm-devcjn-01-a tmp]# cat /tmp/test_service_script_fred
#!/bin/bash

sleep 30&
echo `date` $# args: $@ > $0.log
```

When called from the shell, passing an array, works as expected:

```
[root@vm-devcjn-01-a tmp]# args=("THIS" "THAT" "123456")
[root@vm-devcjn-01-a tmp]# ./test_service_script_fred  ${args[@]}
[root@vm-devcjn-01-a tmp]# tail test_service_script_fred.log
Wed 18 Oct 19:36:51 BST 2023 3 args: THIS THAT 123456
```

However, when called via a systemd service, with the same array passed via EnvironmentFile, it doesn't:

```
[root@vm-devcjn-01-a tmp]# cat StartArgs
args=("THIS" "THAT" "123456")

[root@vm-devcjn-01-a tmp]# systemctl cat test@fred
# /etc/systemd/system/test@.service
# The test service unit template file
#
# version=$Header

[Unit]
Description=test %I instance

[Service]
Type=forking
KillMode=process
WorkingDirectory=/tmp
EnvironmentFile=/tmp/StartArgs
ExecStart=/bin/bash /tmp/test_service_script_%i ${args[@]}

[root@vm-devcjn-01-a tmp]# systemctl start test@fred
[root@vm-devcjn-01-a tmp]# tail test_service_script_fred.log
Wed 18 Oct 19:39:12 BST 2023 1 args:
```

Comment: AFAIK, shell environment variables can only be KEY=VALUE pairs and they do not support arrays.  A common multi value environment variable is `$PATH` which is a single string parsed with a separator (`:`), you could try something like that for your use case.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try something like that.